# Which Database to use for social networking android application?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, relational-database

I have recently started to built some android applications now I want to add a back-end database to my android application.

Can anyone tell me that which database to use and how to go proceed with it?
I have read lot of articles and links about SQLite, Parse, MongoDB and other relational databases.

My requirements are like number of user would be more than million and most of the data shared by the users amongst all of them would be in text only. And all the users would be related to each other.

I know there are many articles out on internet but I am not able to find one stop solution, I am a beginner in this please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant "M**o**ngoDB."  I wouldn't use MongoDB.  It is not a relational database.  It is a NoSQL database.  If the database is going to be embedded in the application, then SQLite would be ideal.  If the database is going to house the communication data of the users, then you'll need a back-end platform.

Facebook uses MySQL.  PostgreSQL is ACID compliant.  This has its advantages.  But MySQL and Postgres would be ideal of back-end database platforms.  I'm not sure if the fact that it is an Android application matters. Oracle licensing can be expensive.  Installing it can be complicated.  SQL Server would wed you to Windows.  I think MySQL or Postgres would be the best options.

Answer (score 1):

AS Propulsion said Mongo is not a relational database but I think that could be an advantage. NoSQL databases provide great advantages such as great posibilities to manage big amounts of data in the server side of your app. Another advantage is the scability that they provide. If you start an app with an small amount of data, and your app is sudenlly a great success, a NoSQL database will be easier to scale. On the other hand relational databases are often easier to use for most programmers as well almost everybody knows how to use them and of course the native solution to manage data in Android is SqlLite which is a relational database. And of course have a relational database in ayour app and a NoSQL database in your server could be a nightmare ar the moment of synchronization.
I could recomend to have a look to couchbase. It is a NoSQL database. It has a version nor mobile devices (at least Android and IOS) and a version for the server side. And for me the biggest advantage is that it can handle the synchranization of data almost automatically (wich can be very hard to program). check here http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile